# How can I direct traffic to Subdomains in /etc/hosts?

Tags: unix, dns, subdomain

I tried to put the line to /etc/hosts:

> IP math.com mathworld.com

where IP was supposed to be the IP of http://mathworld.wolfram.com/classroom/. I pinged the site, and I realised that I must direct traffic with some other tools:

> ping mathworld.wolfram.com/
>
> ping: cannot resolve mathworld.wolfram.com/: Unknown host

So the question arises:

> How can I direct traffic to subdomains, similar to the above subdomain?

Comment: Edit your question: the slash at the end of mathworld.wolfram.com/ is enough to prevent ping to work.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You seem to be confused about networking terminology.

http://mathworld.wolfram.com/classroom/ is a URL, not a domain name. It has no IP address. `mathworld.wolfram.com` *is* a domain name and has an IP address.

Also, `mathworld.wolfram.com` is a subdomain of `wolfram.com` which is a subdomain of the `com` top level domain.

mathworld.wolfram.com is *not* a subdomain of mathworld.com

The `/etc/hosts` is not powerful enough to map all subdomains of a domain to the same place. You will need to type them all out, *or* go into proper DNS server configuration (such as `named.conf`).

Comment: Why does the command "ping mathworld.wolfram.com" do not work for me? The error is "ping: sendto: No route to host".

Comment: If the sentence "mathworld.wolfram.com is a domain name and has an IP address" is right, the ping should work. Why does it not work?

Comment: Is your internet connection correctly set up? "No route to host" means the IP address was found, but cannot be reached.

Comment: @Artelius: Yes, it is. I can access the site with any of my browsers, such as Opera and Firefox, but I cannat ping. I tested to ping in Ubuntu and Mac OS, but the same message appers. I cannot understand the reason if the site "mathworld.wolfram.com" really has an IP.

Comment: The same error appears with the site "wolfram.com", when I do:
ping wolfram.com

Comment: Web browers tend to have their own DNS engines built in, but ping relies on the OS's DNS system. It could be that your OS's name resolution is misconfigured.

Answer (score 1):

Your ping failed because you had a trailing / on the hostname, which isn't valid.

Are you trying to create your own local alias URL that drops you into the right part of that specific third-party URL?

That can't work on its own, because:

1. the third party site will see *your* hostname alias in the `Host:` HTTP headers, which it won't recognise
2. it won't drop you into the right subdirectory of their server

To make this work you'd need to point that local alias towards a web server that you control, and then have that server issue an HTTP redirect to the real site.

Comment: The bigger issue is that mathworld.wolfram.com isn't in the /etc/hosts file.

Comment: Why should it be? that's what DNS is for.  It looks like he's just trying to create local shortcuts for those URLs.